# DeltaCopy (Rsync for windows) giving an error on task run

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, rsync

I was suggested DeltaCopy to set up a nightly backup between two Windows 2008 R2 servers.

After setting up the server side (Amazon EC2 instance where files will be backed to) and setting up the client side (server to be backed up), I attempted to setup a simple task of backing up a single word document.

When running the task manually, the following error appears:

rsync: change_dir#3 "Desktop" (in Backup) failed: No such file or directory (2)

rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at /home/lapo/packaging/rsync-3.0.4-1/src/rsync-3.0.4/main.c(614) [receiver=3.0.4]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (5 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /home/lapo/packaging/rsync-3.0.4-1/src/rsync-3.0.4/io.c(632) [sender=3.0.4]

Error in rsync protocol data stream
Rsync.exe returned an error. Will try again. This is retry number 1 of 5

Executing: rsync.exe  -v -rlt -z --chmod=a=rw,Da+x --delete "/cygdrive/C/Users/[user]/Desktop/Sizes.docx" "[server public IP]::Backup/Desktop/Sizes.docx"
sending incremental file list

I am very confused about this error and haven't come up with any solutions after a long time searching.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well does the directory `Backup/Desktop/` exist?  BTW, are you really doing a backup directly to an rsync daemon and not over ssl/ssh?  What do you see if you do run the command `rsync [server public IP]::Backup`, exactly like that.  It should give you a list of what is on the server.

Comment: When running that command I get "drwxrwxrwx           0 2012/03/12 12:34:15 ." That's it.

Comment: Which indicates that the directory `Backup/Desktop` doesn't already exist on the server.  Try creating it, then re-running your sync.